# SQL Trigger Calling out Domain\Group

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2019

I am creating a trigger in SQL Server 2019 to secure the number of connections users can have into my SQL server.

I am having an issue getting my SYSDBAs access using the domain group. I would rather do this instead of identifying every single user in the trigger.

How do I identify the group in the script below instead of DOMAIN\sysdba?

I am trying to set the DOMAIN\group to limit the number of connections it makes and keeping certain DOMAIN\users to having a different number of connections.

---

Added code from SergeyA below. Still thing I am missing the logic here. The `CASE ORIGINAL_LOGIN` is taking precedence.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Secure_SQL
 ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa account'
 FOR LOGON
 AS
BEGIN
declare @session_cnt int, @is_sysasmin int
select @session_cnt=count(*) from sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE
is_user_process = 1 AND original_login_name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
-- change context to actual user to check if there any sysadmin role
execute as login=original_login()
select @is_sysasmin=count(*) from sys.login_token where name='sysadmin'
REVERT
IF (Select COUNT(1) from sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND original_login_name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN*() ) > 
(CASE ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
    WHEN 'sa account' THEN 40
    WHEN 'DOMAIN\sysdba' THEN 150
    WHEN 'DOMAIN\sysdba' THEN 150
    ELSE 1
 END)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The login [' + ORIGINAL_LOGIN() + '] has exceeeded its current session limit.'
        ROLLBACK;;
    END
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SergeyA for the support with the code and the logic. That was the logic I needed to get the `sysadmin` group. Using that I used it as a query to make a variable for it the user is a `sysadmin`. If they are they should have unlimited access. Then I limited the other accounts.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Secure_SQL
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa account'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    declare @session_cnt int, @is_sysasmin int
    select @session_cnt=count(*) from sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND original_login_name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
-- change context to actual user to check if there any sysadmin role
    execute as login=original_login()
    select @is_sysasmin=count(*) from sys.login_token where name='sysadmin'
    REVERT
    IF ($is_sysadmin <> 1) 
        BEGIN
             IF (Select COUNT(1) from sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1    AND original_login_name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN*() ) > 
             (CASE ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
                WHEN 'sa account' THEN 40
                WHEN 'DOMAIN\sysdba' THEN 150
                WHEN 'DOMAIN\sysdba' THEN 150
                ELSE 1
        END)
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'The login [' + ORIGINAL_LOGIN() + '] has exceeeded its current session limit.'
                ROLLBACK;
        END
    END
END
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to check if the login have a membership of sysadmin server role via some of the group you can run

```
select * from sys.login_token where name='sysadmin'
```

update.

The problem is: to view sys.dm_exec_sessions the account need to have VIEW SERVER STATE permission but sys.login_token returns info about your own session. I think the solution could be changing context to ORIGINAL_LOGIN()

> Where would I add this in the script given?

```
CREATE TRIGGER Secure_SQL
 ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa account'
 FOR LOGON
 AS
BEGIN

declare @session_cnt int, @is_sysasmin int
select @session_cnt=count(*) from sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND original_login_name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()

-- change context to actual user to check if there any sysadmin role
execute as login=original_login()

select @is_sysasmin=count(*) from sys.login_token where name='sysadmin'

revert 

if -- put your logic here
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The login [' + ORIGINAL_LOGIN() + '] has exceeeded its current session limit.'
        ROLLBACK;;
    END
END;
```

Comment: Note that this would _require_ the DBAs to all be sysadmins.  You can use the same technique to check the login's domain group memberships.  sys.login_token has a row for your login and a row for each server role you're in, and a role for each windows group you're in.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft can you provide an example? I am new to this kind of coding for SQL.

Comment: @SergeyA thanks for the code updates but if I login with my domain accounts as part of a the sysadmin group it still limits me.

Comment: You mean @is_sysasmin=0 for you? Can you run select * from sys.login_token where name='sysadmin' as yourself?

Comment: @SergeyA for me it is 1. But when I use the if statement from my original post using the CASE ORIGINAL_LOGIN it still limits me to 1 connection. It looks like I need to change the IF statement in the logic but I am confused as to how I would do that.