# SQL Trigger Connection Case With NT AUTHORITY

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2019

I am trying to limit the connections to my SQL using a CASE to monitor the connections as laid out [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331611/sql-trigger-calling-out-domain-group).
In the CASE I am trying to add the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE to the case. Yet when it connects to the database it is immediately dropped because of the Trigger. But it doesn't drop my domain accounts. How do I get the NETWORK SERVICE account to connect without an issue.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Secure_SQL
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa account'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    declare @session_cnt int, @is_sysasmin int
    select @session_cnt=count(*) from sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND original_login_name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
-- change context to actual user to check if there any sysadmin role
    execute as login=original_login()
    select @is_sysasmin=count(*) from sys.login_token where name='sysadmin'
    REVERT
    IF ($is_sysadmin <> 1) 
        BEGIN
             IF (Select COUNT(1) from sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1    AND original_login_name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN*() ) > 
             (CASE ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
                WHEN 'sa account' THEN 40
                WHEN 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' THEN 150  --Account Fails login due to trigger
                WHEN 'DOMAIN\sysdba' THEN 150
                ELSE 1
        END)
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'The login [' + ORIGINAL_LOGIN() + '] has exceeeded its current session limit.'
                ROLLBACK;
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: @Charlieface Message: "Logon failed for login 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' due to trigger execution

Comment: Are there any other messages? Can you check the error log? Can you change the trigger to, instead of `PRINT... ROLLBACK;` to just `THROW 50001, N'The login has exceeeded its current session limit.', 0;`

Comment: @Charlieface could it be a problem with the user account containing spaces?

Comment: @Charlieface there are no other errors btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So messing around with some suggestions and testing account actions I changed the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE to DOMAIN\COMPUTER$ and it can now login without a problem. This makes sense as SQL is on the machine but doesn't see the computers service accounts as what they are and see the connection as a Computer connection.